# Why am I able to bypass a website's authentication?

Tags: authentication, web-application, vulnerability

I am blackbox testing a vulnerable website. The website in question is accessed using HTTP and to reach its content one is prompted with a field to enter the password (presumably set by the admin) at the homepage. If I enter a wrong password, I get the "incorrect password" notification.

However, after entering the URI path `/index.html`, the content is seen, without entering any password. If I click any link there and get referred to a `http://website.com/page.php`, I get prompted with the authentication field again but if I replace `.php` with `.html`, I see the content that is supposed to be password protected. I am also allowed to access the `images` directory.

From development point of view, what is done wrong here that allows to bypass the authentication and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

> From development point of view, what is done wrong here that allows to bypass the authentication

Putting private content in a place where it can be accessed with no controls.

It seems that the website designer has written some php scripts that check the authentication details and serve up the content if it passes but has forgotten that he has put the actual content files in a place where the web server will just serve them up.

> and how should it be fixed?

The quickest fix would be to reconfigure the web server not to serve .html files from that directory but that seems like a band aid. Directories where secret stuff is stored should be kept seperate from directories to be served up directly by the webserver and ideally should be completely outside the "web root".

Comment: If the content is outside the webserver, where should it be placed and how would it be reached by authenticated users? The whole page, except the initial login prompt is secret in my case. I'm aware that this may be a broad question, so even if you linked me to an article or a wikipedia page on the topic, I would be thankful.